# Is there any library in Python that can parse a HiveQL database and return the Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, hiveql

Is there any library in Python that can parse a HiveQL database and return the Abstract Syntax Tree?  In fact, I need to know how many output fields there are in the HiveQL, and how they are grouped.

I can do it with regular expressions; however, I think it's tricky, and easily fails when the HiveQL is too complicated.

Comment: I just use the "explain" statement to get the AST, but it's a string. I want a python lib to parse it into an object, so i can see what's is the tree really like.

Comment: the output of "explain" is a nested string, i used pyparsing to settle this problem.